# Collection is serializing with the each-object key being the pluralized key, cannot figure out why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

We've got a simple api endpoint that works like so:

```
def index
  render json: Country.all
end
```

This is unfortunately giving us this output:

```
{
    "countries" => [
        [0] {
            "countries" => {
                      "id" => 1,
                     "iso" => "US",
                    "iso3" => "USA",
                "iso_name" => "UNITED STATES",
                    "name" => "United States of Foo",
                 "numcode" => 840
            }
        },
        [1] {
            "countries" => {
                      "id" => 2,
                     "iso" => "CA",
                    "iso3" => "CAN",
                "iso_name" => "CANADA",
                    "name" => "Canada",
                 "numcode" => 124
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice that the key for each individual object is the *plural* form of the key.

However, when we set the endpoint to work like so

```
def inded
  render json: {countries: Country.all}
end
```

The output looks like so:

```
{
    "countries" => [
        [0] {
            "country" => {
                      "id" => 1,
                     "iso" => "US",
                    "iso3" => "USA",
                "iso_name" => "UNITED STATES",
                    "name" => "United States of Foo",
                 "numcode" => 840
            }
        },
        [1] {
            "country" => {
                      "id" => 2,
                     "iso" => "CA",
                    "iso3" => "CAN",
                "iso_name" => "CANADA",
                    "name" => "Canada",
                 "numcode" => 124
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I.e., correct.

However, setting the key like `{countries: Country.all}` is bad form, and I'd like to understand why rails is serializing each element with the collection key rather than the object key (that is, why it's plural and not singular for each `country`).

We have not overridden `to_json` or any other serialization methods. We are using the default rails model serializer (I tried making an explicit serializer, but there was no change in behavior). I cannot, for the life of me, figure out why it is pluralizing these keys.

**Edit:** There is even more weirdness. I was incorrect about the explicit serializer, when I set up a serializer (with just the attributes as it normally displays), I get this:

```
{
    "countries" => [
        [0] {
                  "id" => 1,
                 "iso" => "US",
                "iso3" => "USA",
            "iso_name" => "UNITED STATES",
                "name" => "United States of Foo",
             "numcode" => 840
        },
        [1] {
            "countries" => {
                      "id" => 2,
                     "iso" => "CA",
                    "iso3" => "CAN",
                "iso_name" => "CANADA",
                    "name" => "Canada",
                 "numcode" => 124
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The first object *has no key*, and every other one is plural. I tested both in tests, and confirmed by making the actual API call.

I can't find anything that would override this other than an overridden `<=>` and `to_s`. These should not affect output in this way?

Comment: What version of Rails is this? To clarify, you're not using ActiveModel::Serializer, are you?

Comment: `3.2.18`, using AM::S.

Comment: What version of AM::S do you have locked?

Comment: `0.8.1`, but I upgraded to `0.9.0` and it behaved the same.

Comment: This probably isn't related to your issue, but I'd recommend not using `0.9.x` - it's kind of the bastard child of AM::S at this point. `0.10` is going to be based off `0.8`.

Comment: Can you post your serializer?

Comment: It's deleted now, but it was just `attributes :id, :iso, ...`.

Comment: Do you have an initializer for AM:S or a BaseSerializer you subclass?

Comment: Base, but it's empty and inherits from AM:S.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, I think you copied and pasted something wrong, or you might just be confused.

Both outputs have the same results: Countries (Plural) as the main response, and country(Singular) for each individual inside countries. Or am I misreading?

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening here is that you're trying to specify the root key in a way that AM::S doesn't support.

Instead of `render json: { countries: Country.all }`, I'd recommend trying `render json: Country.all, root: "countries"` (specifying the root key is unnecessary if you're calling the serializer from within CountriesController, otherwise you need it to get the functionality you desire).

See https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable#arrays for more information.

Comment: Sorry, `render json: {countries: Country.all}` is what works. When, instead, we try to remove the extraneous wrapping hash and just `render json: Country.all`, is when these weird issues crop up. It correctly gives the root key of `countries`, but the keys for the individual items are incorrect.